# Runge Kutta "Relaxed Constraints"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I am reading about implicit Runge-Kutta methods as well as collocation methods,  and I am struggling to understand the conditions of "relaxed constraints" of implicit methods shown on page 3 of this [article](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1964-18-085/S0025-5718-1964-0159424-9/S0025-5718-1964-0159424-9.pdf). (The relaxed conditions are simply that values $ c_1,c_2 ... c_s$ are distinct and $(\sum b_i =1)  \land b_i \neq 0 $)

From the article, $A(p)$ implies that Runge-Kutta methods will be accurate up to $O(h^p)$

How does one derive the equations for constraints $B(p),C(p),D(p)$ and $E(p,d)$? And what does each constraint mean?

In Theorem 1, it states that $A(p) \implies B(p)$. However, collocation methods have a [theory on superconvergence](https://na.math.kit.edu/marlis/download/meetings/08Oberwolfach/problems/gnibook-chap2.pdf) that will have methods of order $p>s$ if $B(p)$ is satisfied. Is this theory only tied specifically to collocation methods, or can I use $B(p)$ to determine the order for any Runge-Kutta?

Comment: As an example, on ([slide 8](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/IRK.pdf)), why does order 5 require the satisfaction of $B(5), C(2), D(2)$?